# Unable to make a transition work between 0.13.3 and 3.0.0 (react-router)

Tags: react-router

I'm looking to replace code in an online tutorial that demonstrates transitions from v0.x --> v3.x using react-router.

The example is straightforward where a function is run on the client side confirming with the user if they really want to transition from the current page to the requested page/route (the aboutPage in the example). This works fine when using the code provided in the tutorial, however I'm trying to convert this from the tutorial - which uses react-router v0.x - to the stable version of react-router 3.0.0.

I've looked through the upgrade guides provided as part of the react-router documentation, but unfortunately have not been able to mimic the same behaviour. The good news is that I've come close - where the aboutPage will either be rendered, or not rendered, depending on whether the user selects [OK], or [Cancel] when prompted. The problem is that with the code I have written, when the user chooses NOT to view the page, it isn't rendered, however the URL still changes (i.e. http://server/aboutPage) even though the aboutPage isn't rendered. How do I get it so that the URL remains the same if the user selects cancel?

example...

## aboutPage.js

### version 0.13.3

```
var React = require ('react');
var About = React.createClass({
    statics: {
        willTransitionTo: function(transition, params, query, callback) {
            if (!confirm("Are you sure you really want to make a transition to the about page?!")) {
                transition.about();
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        }
    },
    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>About</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = About;
```

### version 3.0.0

```
var React = require ('react');
var About = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>About</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = About;
```

## main.js

### version 0.13.3

```
var React = require('react');

var Router = require('react-router');
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Route = Router.Route;
var NotFoundRoute = Router.NotFoundRoute;
var Redirect = Router.Redirect;

var routes = (
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={require('./app')}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={require('./homePage')} />
    <Route name="about" handler={require('./aboutPage')} />
</Route>
);
module.exports = routes;
```

### version 3.0.0

```
$ = jQuery = require("jquery");

var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var hashHistory = require('react-router').hashHistory
var IndexRoute = require('react-router').IndexRoute;
var IndexLink = require('react-router').IndexLink;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="myContent" className="container-fluid">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});


const checkUserIsSure = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
    (nextState, replace, callback) => { 
        console.log("main/reactdom.render/route-about: entering");
        if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to view a page this boring?")) {
            console.log("you don't want to visit a boring page");
            callback("error message from callback damien")
        } else {
            console.log("you do want to visit a boring page");
            callback();
        }
        console.log("main/checkUserIsSure: leaving...");
}

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} >
            <IndexRoute component={require('./homePage')} />
            <Route path="about" component={require('./components/about/aboutPage')} onEnter={checkUserIsSure}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v3, you can set a leave hook for a component using the `setRouteLeaveHook` provided by the `context.router` (which you can also access by wrapping your component with the `withRouter` higher order component). There is an example in the [confirming navigation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md) documentation.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var withRouter = ReactRouter.withRouter;
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;

var HomePage = withRouter(React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.routerWillLeave);
  },

  routerWillLeave: function() {
    return 'Leaving me already?';
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks Paul - this is a great link and I have to admit I missed it!

It's _almost_ exactly what I want. I want the same functionality, but when 'entering' a page, rather than 'leaving' a page. I made a guess, but routerWillEnter didn't seem to work?